# How do you access the second element of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary called one, and from it I extracted the first element of the dictionary by doing this:

```py
first1 = one.items()
first = list(first1)[:1]
print(first)
```

But now I want to print only the second element of the dictionary. If I do this:

```py
first1 = one.items()
first = list(first1)[:2]
print(first)
```

It prints out both the first element and the second element, but I want only the second one. How can I do this? Is there a special symbol that helps? If you know, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Please retake the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow is not a substitute for tutorials. Accessing single elements of a list is the _first thing_ that any decent tutorial on lists will cover. There are many good ones available online.

Comment: This question is 100% on topic.  "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon means to slice the list, instead try this:

```
first1 = one.items()
first = list(first1)[1]
print(first)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet I think you meant this:

```py
first1 = one.items()
first = list(first1)[0]
print(first)
```

This then leads to finding the second item like this:

```py
first1 = one.items()
first = list(first1)[1]
print(first)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't include a colon:

```
first1 = one.items()
first = list(first1)[1]
print(first)
```